# Matching Graph Drawing

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

How could I draw a graph that is connected, $3$-regular that has both a cut vertex and a perfect matching?  I know every simple $3$-regular graph with no cut-edge has a perfect matching, but not sure how to draw a graph to meet these criteria.

Answer (score 1):

See example below. Edges of one of 4 perfect matchings are marked by red color.

[image]